# android ndk undefined reference to `Add(int, int)'

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to use an  C++ library in my Android project. This library uses the Add(int a,int b) function. I know that Add(int a,int b)  is a function defined in the  C++ library (calc.so).

I want to use android studio way to deal with, rather than write your own android.mk file.

But,  when I try to compile a library that contains calls to this function, I receive a runtime error: Error:(18) undefined reference

to `Add(int, int)'

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs =['src/main/nativeLibs']
    }
}

 ndk {
        moduleName "MyJni" 
        stl "stlport_static"
        ldLibs "log"
        cFlags "-D WEBRTC_ANDROID -D WEBRTC_POSIX"

 }



JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_www_astest_com_MainActivity_getStringFromNative(JNIEnv *env,
                                                         jobject obj, jstring path) {


return  Add(1,2);}
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it will help to you. So, it will helpfull to others as well.